# Cannot establish TLS with client When using selenium to visit website

Tags: selenium, ssl, mitmproxy

I'm trying to run Mitmdump to collect HTTP/HTTPS requests. When I run `mitmdump` inside the `venv`, it reported:

```
Proxy server listening at http://*:8080
127.0.0.1:43382: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:43384: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:43382: GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt
              << 200 OK 8b
127.0.0.1:43390: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:43392: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:43390: GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt?ipv4
              << 200 OK 8b
127.0.0.1:43384: CONNECT location.services.mozilla.com:443
 << Cannot establish TLS with client (sni: location.services.mozilla.com): TlsException("SSL handshake error: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca')],)",)
```

I guess this may be caused by the wrong CA. I used a CA got from `mitmproxy/test/mitmproxy/data/confdir`, it's `mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem`, it worked in several months ago, now it doesn't work, I also tried `/root/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.crt`, it reported the same error. I really don't know why. (T^T)

Any help will be thankful!

Here are some environment information:

```
Mitmproxy: 5.2
Python:    3.6.5
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
Platform:  Linux-5.4.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
Firfox: 75.0
Selenium: 3.14
geckodriver: 0.25.0
```

Here are commands I used to set CA:

```
openssl x509 -in /root/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem -inform PEM -out /root/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.crt
cp /root/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/mitmproxy-ca.crt
echo "extra/mitmproxy-ca.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
update-ca-certificates
```

The code I used to visit website is:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts, seleniumwire_options={'verify_ssl': False})
browser.header_overrides = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'}
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

mitmproxy auto-generates its CA certificate on startup in `~/.mitmproxy/`. If your client doesn't trust this certificate, connections will fail. You can also install it by visiting `http://mitm.it` while using mitmproxy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer@Maximilian Hils. I'm running mitmproxy inside a Ubuntu18.04 container without GUI, so I may not be able to install CA by visiting `mitm.it` since I guess it needs me  to click some button, right? And I'm visiting lots of websites actually, all of them show this error, I don't know why, could you give me more hints? I really appreciate that!

Comment: Was it resolved @LumosRen ?

Comment: @LumosRen you can download and trust the certificate in Ubuntu containers like this: `curl http://mitm.it/cert/pem --output /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mitmproxy-ca-cert.crt && update-ca-certificates` with http_proxy set to your proxy.